# (GWTP) Can "placeManager.revealPlace(request)" open a URL in a new Tab?

Tags: gwt, gwtp

In GWTP, to open a URL in a new tab, we can use this:

```
PlaceRequest request =new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.getorder).with("myID", myID);
String url =
Window.Location.createUrlBuilder().setHash(placeManager.buildHistoryToken(request)).buildString();
Window.open(url, "_blank", null);
```

Can we **not to use** `Window.open` & just use `placeManager` to achive the same thing (ie open a URL in a new Tab).

```
PlaceRequest request =new PlaceRequest(NameTokens.getorder).with("myID", myID);
placeManager.revealPlace(request);
// this code will open the url (ex: mydomain.com#getorder;myID=15 ) in the current browser.
```

The problem of `Window.open(url, "_blank", null);` is that sometime it opens to new tab & sometime it opens to a new Window which is inconsistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
Window.open(url, "", "");
```

or

```
Window.open(url, "", null);
```